# Delete all points outside the contour of a WMS raster map

Tags: qgis, delete, point

I have two layers in QGIS. One WMS raster layer with a country map and one layer with points. It looks like this:
[image]

I want to remove all the points that lie outside the contours of the country map, so I can just keep the points that lies inside the country. How can I do this easier than removing all the points one by one?

Comment: is there a WFS server associated with the WMS?

Answer (score 3):

As described below, you can select points in or out of your contour by `Spatial Query`.

1. On your country layer where you have contours, click on the outermost contour to select.
2. Open the menu `Vector | Spatial Query | Spatial Query`
3. It will open the `Spatial Query` window.
4. Select source features from: `Your points`
5. Where the feature: `Within`
6. Reference features of: `Your polygon (Contour)` - `Selected geometries`
7. And use the result to: `Create new selection`
8. Click on <kbd>Apply</kbd>
9. You will see `Result feature ID's` lists selected points.
10. <kbd>Close</kbd> to close this window.
11. Open the Attribute table of your points layer. Selected points will be highlighted.
12. Click on `Invert selection` icon or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.
13. Enter `Edit mode` (pencil icon) and  `Delete selected features`.

---

**EDIT**

Step 0. Please create a polygon layer which follows the contour (is it a country boarderline, perhaps?) by digitizing.

Comment: There won't be a contour though, the WMS (country layer) is an image

Comment: ack, then the contour in the question is...oh... thanks @nmtoken !

Comment: I dont have a polygon now, but a line. Lets say its a coastline. How can I then delete all the  points to the right of the line?

Comment: @LarsFredrik um...I probably do not understand the context. Could you post a new question, perhaps? Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Looking back (received comment from [nmtoken](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/27874/nmtoken)), I found I have completely misunderstood the question.

[image]

QGIS toolbar has a `Select Feature(s)` tool. When you click on small black triangle, it opens a drop-down menu. You will see `Select Features by Freehand`.

Now you can draw the selection polygon following the contour line you see on the WMS background image. These selected points can, of course, be deleted at once.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe what caused the confusion was because I didnt mention it was a WMS layer at first, but edited the text later. Maybe its better to find another layer that is not WMS and have a contour?

Comment: @LarsFredrik Thanks, and sorry, it was just my mistake. Yes, if you can find a polygon contour layer, it will be definitely useful to define the area to choose / exclude points.